# Software vulnerabilities in libraries

Tags: security, libraries

If I have a vulnerability in a library, and I have that library installed, but the application does not declare it or call it, is there anyway that someone can forcibly call it?

Comment: What kind of application you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The third paragraph in this link should answer your question:
https://www.contrastsecurity.com/security-influencers/libraries-and-application-security-part-three-unused-libraries